# Unexpected DNS queries

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns, dnsmasq

I see lots of DNS queries in my dnsserver (`dnsmasq`)

```
 query[A] cdn.switchadhub.com from xxx
 query[A] delivery.g.switchadhub.com from xxx
 query[A] delivery.swid.switchadhub.com from xxx
```

What are those sites?

When I recorded those queries, no browser was running on the system. The DNS server is listening in a localhost interface. That makes me think that there is a process running in the system doing those queries.

How can I find out which process is sending those requests?

I am on Ubuntu 18.04.01.

### UPDATE

Stopping and restarting the dns server got rid of the strange queries. It seems there was some kind of recursion at play?

Comment: I've noticed something similar in the past and in my case it was the Name Service Cache Daemon (ncsd)